# What is the practical relationship between the streams memory bandwidth benchmark and the potential speedup from running MPI locally?

Tags: mpi, latency, memory-access

I ran the streams memory bandwidth benchmark (https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/) on a computer with 10 processors. The benchmark indicated that after 3 or 4 processors, the speedup plateaued at about 3x. What are the practical implications of this result for the performance of an MPI code? For simplicity, assume the program is running multiple processes locally on this multicore machine only. Does this mean that if you are running a memory access intensive program, then you will not be able to get more than 3x speedup, even if you use all the cores? If you ran a program that was not memory-access intensive, could you theoretically get the full 10x? If you simultaneously ran two or three memory access intensive programs, each using three processors, would they each be able to get 3x speedup, or would they interfere with each other and slow each other down as they all simultaneously pulled from RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speedup is about how much parallelism exist in the code. Moreover, any resource could also become a bottleneck depending on the type of the application. If your application is memory intensive, then you will be limited by the memory bandwidth. If its not memory intensive, and it is highly parallel (take Monte Carlo sampling as an example), then you will get close to the full speedup from your cores.

To answer your last question (multiple memory-intensive): at the end of the day we rely on memory controllers to do read/write. So it depends on the memory banks and where the physical pages are allocated from. So, any of the two situations that you mentioned could happen.

Comment: So is this a drawback to using computers with a larger number of processors? Specifically, could you get better performance, on a cluster, by running an MPI job on 8 computers with 4 processors, rather than one computer with 32 processors? The latter would not require communication between nodes, but the former has eight separate memory controllers on eight separate nodes?

Comment: I wouldn't say its a drawback to use a larger number of processors. *Application* plays a key role. Remember MPI is all about communication among nodes and the fact that you can run a larger problem (you have x * number of nodes of RAM). Interconnect plays a key role and today's infiniband networks can drive GB/s (depending on the message size). So there are parameters to take into account to answer your last question...and the answer is: it depends.

Comment: Cool, I think "it depends" is an answer to the question. I was asking if it is possible that distributing across more cores with fewer processors could be faster, and you're saying yes, it could be faster. Definitely, I understand it depends, specifically on whether local memory latency within a process is more important or latency due to data exchange between processes is more important.